# What is the word for when someone talks like the people from a certain area?

Tags: single-word-requests

What is the political strategy called when you use certain dialect and mention certain things in order to appeal to people in a target area? This is done a lot during campaigns in order to give yourself credibility and ethos, since people are more likely to trust/believe someone who sounds like them.

Comment: If done intentionally it could be seen as a form of pandering.

Comment: @GeorgeWhite that sounds like the right word! Thanks

Answer (score 2):

There's a term **code-switching** that can "refer to switching among dialects, styles or registers". ([wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code-switching)) The article goes on to note that such shifts "when performed by public figures such as politicians, are sometimes criticized as signalling inauthenticity or insincerity".

Answer (score 0):

Now that I've read your question properly. I'm not sure IF there's a word to describe that, if there is then I'm equally as interested.

I believe it's just a form of appealing to the people. People tend to see politicians as 'higher ups' so they need to appeal to people to seem more normal and relatable.

Comment: Welcome to English Language & Usage! Please try to add references to support your answer.

Answer (score -1):

If done intentionally it could be seen as a form of pandering